# python scanning directory for files

Tags: python

So I have a script that needs to do 3 things at different intervals on a server.

1. Scan FTP for files newer than 24 hours if so download(using subprocess),
2. scan location 1 and if files exist move files and rename based on where the files came from(using subprocess),
3. scan directory and if files exist upload files to a different FTP(using subprocess).

Everything is fine except for this; on the 3rd scan (which is identical to 2nd scan) for some reason the script does not want to move beyond "for root, dirs, files in"

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess 
import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt

# Local Directories 
N_dir_dest = '/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/_Jonatha/BeeCell/N_dest' # Directory where the      NICK source video files needs to be downloaded to
M_dir_dest = '/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/_Jonatha/BeeCell/M_dest' # Directory where the     NICK source video files needs to be downloaded to
encode_dest1 = '/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/_Jonatha/BeeCell/encode_dest1' # Encoding Directory where source videos are moved to after being downloaded and renamed
encodeDrop_dir = '/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/_Jonatha/BeeCell/encodeDrop_dir' # Files ready for uploading to BeeCell FTP 

#Script Starts

while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        if dt.now().hour in range(20, 23):
            print "Starting to Scan UK FTP for source files - time is: %s" % dt.now()
            thedownloadprocess = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/_Jonatha/BeeCell/BeeCell_FTP_incoming.py"])
            thedownloadprocess.communicate()
            time.sleep(3600)


        elif dt.now().minute in range(01, 15) or dt.now().minute in range(31, 45):
            time.sleep(10)
            print "Scanning %s and %s - time is: %s" % (N_dir_dest, M_dir_dest, dt.now())
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(N_dir_dest) or os.walk(M_dir_dest):
                for file in files:
                    path_to_file = os.path.join(root, file)
                    if os.path.isfile(path_to_file) and file.endswith(('.mov', '.mpg', '.mp4')):
                        print "file: %s found - starting rename process" % path_to_file
                        renameprocess = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/_Jonatha/BeeCell/BeeCell_rname_files.py"])
                        renameprocess.communicate()
                        print "Finished Rename and encode - sleeping for 10 secs- time is: %s" % dt.now()
                        time.sleep(10)
                    else:
                        print "No files in %s or %s" % (N_dir_dest, M_dir_dest)
                        time.sleep(20) 



        elif dt.now().minute in range(16, 30) or dt.now().minute in range(46, 00): # checking every 120 seconds in the minute range 20 - 59
            time.sleep(10)
            print "scanning %s - time is: %s" % (encodeDrop_dir, dt.now())
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(encodeDrop_dir):
                for file in files:
                    path_to_file = os.path.join(root, file)
                    if os.path.isfile(path_to_file) and file.endswith(('.mov', '.mpg', '.mp4')):
                        print "file: %s will be uploaded"
                        Nuploadprocess = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/_Jonatha/BeeCell/BeeCell_FTPupload.py"]) 
                        Nuploadprocess.communicate()
                        print "Finished Upload - sleeping for 10 secs- time is: %s" % dt.now()
                        time.sleep(10)
                    else:
                        print "No files in %s" % encodeDrop_dir
                        time.sleep(10)

        else:
            print "Relaxing"
```

When I run the script the first "elif" runs fine and starts the subprocess if a file is found in the directory - but on the 2nd "elif" it just loops this:

```
elif dt.now().minute in range(16, 30) or dt.now().minute in range(46, 00): # checking every 120 seconds in the minute range 20 - 59
            time.sleep(10)
            print "scanning %s - time is: %s" % (encodeDrop_dir, dt.now())
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(encodeDrop_dir):
```

The loop continues until the dt.now() range moves on. I can't see any difference in the code between the first "elif" and the second "elif" - I am willing to hear any suggestions after wrecking my brain for the last couple of days trying to work out what is going wrong!!??

Ok added print functions:

```
    print "scanning %s - time is: %s" % (encodeDrop_dir, dt.now())
            print "Upload List: %s" % E_dir_oslist
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(encodeDrop_dir):
                print "hello"
                for file in files:
                    print "hello 1"
```

this is the output:

scanning /Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/_Jonatha/BeeCell/encodeDrop_dir - time is: 2013-03-19 18:22:25.345483

Upload List: []

hello

UPDATE: If I move the scan function into the scripts that the subprocess calls - it works. I have not yet found out why it fails if used in the fashion above.

Comment: Intuitively it sounds like you're just not getting any results back from `os.walk(encodeDrop_dir)`, so you don't go into that loop. Maybe print `os.listdir(encodeDrop_dir)` before you start the loop, just to make sure you've got something to loop over?

Comment: BTW you should call dt.now() only once and bind it to a variable, to avoid having strange behaviour when your script is called at HH:59:59.

Comment: `range(start, stop)`: `start` is inclusive, but `stop` is *not*. `range(1, 15)` returns a list with values from 1 through to 14, perhaps you meant `range(1, 16)` instead.. `range(46, 00)` should be replaced with `range(46,60)`.

Comment: "a in range (16,30)" can be expressed as "16 <= a < 30".

Comment: If the third scan "is identical to the second scan", make that a function instead of copying and pasting 14 complex lines of code. That's the only way to guarantee that it actually _is_ identical. I can spot some visible differences even with a quick cursory glance. Trying to guess which of those differences, if any, is relevant to the problem is a whole lot of wasted effort.

Comment: Also, what does "the script does not want to move beyond "for root, dirs, files in" mean? Does it get stuck in that loop forever, and not get back to the outer loop? Or what? If you don't actually _know_ what's happening, add some `print`/`logging.info`/whatever calls in so you can trace what happens when.

Comment: Hi - thank you all for jumping on this so quickly. I am going to try Henry's suggestion on the os.listdir() and from abarnert - I will try and define as function. Regarding the range - over the last two days the last else has caught everything outside of the start stop/range. So at the moment I am not to worried on that.

Comment: Hi abarnet - it loops back to:time.sleep(10)
            print "Scanning %s and %s - time is: %s" - I have already tried to print function to find out where it actually stops and loop back to the beginning

Comment: Tried os.listdir(encodeDrop_dir) there is nothing in the directory - which means that the loop should to go "else" and print that no files exists in the directory but no it just goes back to looping

Comment: Just a small update. If I add the loop inside the subprocess scripts it works. I still have no idea why in the script above the second scan fails. Also for uselpa - if you bind dt.now() to a global variable it only calls the dt.now() once when the script starts. The time will be static. I will close this question.